# jQuery last Element with certain css property

Tags: jquery

I have a list of the same divs which are hidden.  Now there are few of the same div which are not hidden, how do i get the last of them?

Comment: Give us the html so we can see what you mean please

Answer (score 2):

```
var elem = $(".myclass:visible").last();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8Ajh/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `last()` function from a selector that can select the divs that aren't hidden.

http://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 1):

Try http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery last selector

```
$(".cssName :last")
```

[last Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)